# What is the best way to count in a for loop?

Tags: python

I find myself in the need of counting through lists with the help of for loops. What I end up doing is this:

```
L = ['A','B','C','D']

n = 0
for i in L:
    print(L[n])
    n += 1
```

I was wondering if there is a better way for doing this, without having to declare an extra variable `n` every time?

Please keep in mind that this is just a simplified example.  A solution like this would not suffice (although in this example the results are the same):

```
L = ['A','B','C','D']

for i in L:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `print(len(L))`?

Comment: `for index, element in enumerate(L):` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-the-enumerate-function/):

> In Python, the enumerate() function is used to iterate through a list
>   while keeping track of the list items' indices.

Using [`enumerate()`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-the-enumerate-function/):

```
L = ['A','B','C','D']

for index, element in enumerate(L):
      print("{} : {}".format(index,element))    # print(index, L[index])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
0 : A
1 : B
2 : C
3 : D
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate):

```
L = ['A','B','C','D']
for i, x in enumerate(L):
  print(i,x)
```